# How to debug/track PHP session management?

Tags: php, session

I would like to track the PHP session management to better understand what is actually happening.
E.g. I'd like to know, by logging on the Apache error_log file, when the garbage collection of session data starts (see session.gc_maxlifetime).

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: Yes.Do you have any useful contribute to my question ?

Comment: Yes. But You already got your answer, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a [`SessionHandlerInterface`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) and register it using [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).